# Express validator ".isEmpty()" not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

When I try to run my application I get an error saying that text boxes that are not empty are empty.

app.js:
https://pastebin.com/5pbVG7kq

index.hbs:
https://pastebin.com/neVV4X78

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

With express-validator, you need to use the "notEmpty()" function instead of validator's module "isEmpty()", which is not referenced in the readme.md. I tried it out with an empty string and without sending the parametr and it works fine in both cases.

OLD REPLY:

I'm facing the same issue with express-validator. I submitted the issue to the github respository so we have to wait for them to address the problem.

As a workaround in the meantime, you can use the isEmpty() function of the validator package directly.

```js
var validator = require('validator');

validator.isEmpty(string) //returns true or false
```

Also note that validator only accepts a string value and it doesn't coerce the variable passed to it as opposed to express-validator, so you will need to handle the case when the parameter obtained via req.body.param is not sent.

Here is the link to the reported issue: https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator/issues/336

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**2019** **express-validator
6.2.0**
Here is what I use for now and it works perfect

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const {createPost} = require('../controllers/post');

// Import check only form express-validator
const {check} = require('express-validator');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/post',[
    // Title
    check('title').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Title is required.'),

    check('title').isLength({
        min:4,
        max:150
    }).withMessage('Title must be between 4 to 150 characters.'),

    check('body').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Body is required.'),

    check('body').isLength({
        min:4,
        max:2000
    }).withMessage('body must be between 4 to 2000 characters.')

],createPost)
```

** Folder '../controllers/post'**
**post.js**

```
// Import validation result only from expres-validator
const {validationResult } = require('express-validator');

// Post model file with custom implementation. 
 const Post = require('../models/post');


exports.createPost = (req, res) => {

// Grab your validation errors here before making any CREATE operation to your database.
  const errors = validationResult(req);
 if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    const firstError = errors.array().map(error => error.msg)[0];
    return res.status(400).json({ error: firstError });
  }
    const post = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        body: req.body.body
    });


// Now you can safely save your data after check passes.
    post.save()
    .then(result => {
        res.status(200).json({
           post: result
        })
    });
};
```